# AutoMapper - Mapping child properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a view model that looked like this:

```cs
class PersonSectionViewModel
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class PersonViewModel
{
   public PersonSectionViewModel Main { get; set; }
   public PersonSectionViewModel Partner { get; set; }
}
```

And I tried mapping the properties like this, but it's not working at all:

```cs
class PersonDTO 
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string FirstName_2 { get; set; }
  public string LastName_2 { get; set; }
}

CreateMap<PersonDTO, PersonViewModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Main.FirstName,
           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Main.LastName,
           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Partner.FirstName,
           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName_2))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Partner.LastName,
           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName_2))
```

What's the right way of mapping this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with `.ForPath()`.

```cs
CreateMap<PersonDTO, PersonViewModel>()
    .ForPath(dest => dest.Main.FirstName,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
    .ForPath(dest => dest.Main.LastName,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
    .ForPath(dest => dest.Partner.FirstName,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName_2))
    .ForPath(dest => dest.Partner.LastName,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName_2));
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AgeDco)

---

**Reference**

[Use of `.ForPath()` | GitHub](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ForPath&type=)